# Infinite Loop in Page Redirection Function of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am now working on a piece of code of JavaScript which will be used to redirect a page with a shown counter. The problem is, when counter reaches 0, countDown() function gets in an infinite loop which causes the page to remain the same. And of course, I could not resolve the problem yet. Can anyone help?

You can see the problem here: 
http://kibristaodtuvarmis.com/index.html

Code is shown below:

```
var time = 10;
var page = "http://blog.kibristaodtuvarmis.com";


function countDown()
{        
  if (time == 0)
  {
     window.location = page;
     return(0);
  }
  else
  {       
    time--;
    gett("container").innerHTML = time;
  }
}

function gett(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
    if(document.all) return document.all.id;
    if(document.layers) return document.layers.id;
    if(window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}

function init()
{
    if(gett("container"))
    {
        setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        gett("container").innerHTML = time;
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(init, 50);
    }
}

document.onload = init();
```

**EDIT:**

I have done the below changes in countDown() function and problem is resolved:

```
var control = false;
function countDown()
{
  if (time == 0 && control == false)
  { 
     control = true;
     window.location = page;
     return(0);
  }
  else if (time > 0)
  {       
     time--;
     gett("container").innerHTML = time;
  }
  else
  {  
     return(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: window.onload=init; would be my first change, location.replace(page); my second and lastly redirect to another page than the current

Comment: You probably want `document.all[id]` instead of `document.all.id` or better yet, just get rid of everything except `getElementById`.  Unless this is some seriously legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this part of code for by replacing your  complete javascript Code :

```
   var time = 10;
   var page = "http://blog.kibristaodtuvarmis.com";

   function startCount() {
       time = time - 1;
       console.log(time);
       document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = time;
       startCounter();
   }

   function startCounter() {
       if (time !== 0) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               startCount();
           },1000);
       } else {
           location.href = page;
       }
   }
   if (window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener("load", startCount, false);
   } else if (el.attachEvent)  {
     window.attachEvent("load", startCount);
   }
```

I tried it, It works.
Tell me your reply after testing.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
  var b = false; 
  if (time == 0 && b == false)
  { 
     b = true;
     window.location = page;
     return(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting it to stop at 0? Assign the setInterval to a var and then use clearInterval if 0

Answer (score 0):

your setIinterval continues executing before change the window.location and then causes this loop because time is 0 and should launch window.location again

you should clear the interval

```
var IdInterval = setInterval(function () {
//.... code
    }, 10000);
```

and after the first execution of countDown with time==0 then:

```
clearInterval(IdInterval);
```